# Sending contents of autofilled text field to a php file for processing using JQuery, returning the results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a map that when clicked, the latitude and logitude populate some hidden text fields in a form. What I'd like to do is perform some calculations on these coordinates (find the nearest town), populate the 'Townland' field in the form with the name of the town, then submit everything on clicking submit.

I've been trying to do this by using ajax to send the contents of the lat and lng fields to a php file that does the processing, but I can't get it to work. The sql query works when I manually enter latitudes and logitudes instead of trying to pull them from the other file.

Any help would be great, thank you!

The javascript in my php form page to call the php file that does the calculations

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


    $('lat').change(function(){
       var lat=document.getElementById('lat').value;  
        var lng=document.getElementById('lng').value; 
         $.ajax
            ({ 
                url: '../Controller/PRACTICEtown.php',
                data: { var : lat, var : lng},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(result)
                {
                    $('#Townland').value(result);
                }
            });
    });

</script>
```

The external php file that I want to pick up the lat and lng from the above and perform calculations on, returning the name of the town.

```
<?php
 function getTown(){  

 $conn    = Connect();

     /**
 * Use the Haversine Formula to display the 100 closest matches to $origLat, $origLon
 * Only search the MySQL table $tableName for matches within a 10 mile ($dist) radius.
 */


 $origLat = $_POST['lat'];
$origLon = $_POST['lng'];

$dist = 50; // This is the maximum distance (in miles) away from $origLat, $origLon in which to search

$query = "SELECT Townland, lat, lng, 3956 * 2 * 
          ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($origLat - lat)*pi()/180/2),2)
          +COS($origLat*pi()/180 )*COS(lat*pi()/180)
          *POWER(SIN(($origLon-lng)*pi()/180/2),2))) 
          as distance FROM townland WHERE 
          lng between ($origLon-$dist/cos(radians($origLat))*69) 
          and ($origLon+$dist/cos(radians($origLat))*69) 
          and lat between ($origLat-($dist/69)) 
          and ($origLat+($dist/69)) 
          having distance < $dist ORDER BY distance limit 1"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysql_error());

 if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['Townland'] ;
}

}
getTown();
?>
```

Comment: in data you are sending `var` twice. Use other names, different one for each value. Names that match the $_POST you are using in your code

Comment: The result is supposed to appear in the 'Townland' text field in the main form. I currently have it set out like this:
<input type="text" name="townland" id="townland"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


$('lat').change(function(){
   var lat=document.getElementById('lat').value;  
    var lng=document.getElementById('lng').value; 
     $.ajax
        ({ 
            url: '../Controller/PRACTICEtown.php',
            data: { lat : lat, lng : lng},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result)
            {
                $('#Townland').value(result);
            }
        });
});
```

Note ajax data field

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
data: { var : lat, var : lng},
```

use

```
data: { lat : lat, lng : lng},
```

edit: in your comment to your own question you say that the id of your townland input is "**townland**", but in the ajax success function you want to change value of "**Townland**" (Upper Case!)

Comment: have you tried alerting the result in the ajax success function to see if the ajax at least returns the wanted result?

Comment: as i can see in your comment from 20 minutes ago, your townland input has the id "townland" but in the ajax success function you want to change the value of input with id "Townland" (upper case)

Comment: An alert like this? alert(result); I put that in but nothing happened. I changed it to lower case also but nothing. I think I'll just have to try to find a different way to do it.

Comment: if the alert(result); does never trigger it means there was a problem with the ajax request or with the php script. try adding an error function to the ajax and alert the thrown error. 
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert(errorThrown); }